# Can't login to Parse with Facebook account

Tags: facebook, coronasdk, parse-platform

I'm developing in corona. I'm login(using develephant.net mod_parse.lua) into Parse.com with my Facebook account, which did work just fine before. But now I keep getting this error from Parse:
I/Corona (14497): Parse Code: 251
I/Corona (14497): Error: The supplied Facebook session token is expired or invalid.
I/Corona (14497): im logged in

I have checked with Facebook on https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ and get this feedback:
Issued  1392307353 (22 hours ago)
Expires 1397491353 (in about 2 months)
Valid   True
Origin  Mobile Web Faceweb

Did anybody expirience this before have any ideas why this happened?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to find an answer to this solution here: [Parse Facebook login fails with error code 251](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24423227/parse-facebook-login-fails-with-error-code-251)

In your Facebook App, to go Settings -> Advanced and change the "Is your App Secret embedded?" option to "No".