# Parse Facebook login fails with error code 251

Tags: xcode, parse-platform, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-sdk-3.14.x

I'm trying to use Parse Facebook & Twitter login in my app but the problem is I can't get the Facebook login to work.

I'm getting the following error message:

```
    Error Domain=Parse Code=251 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Parse error 251.)" UserInfo=0xa0329c0 {code=251, error=The supplied Facebook session token is expired or invalid.
```

I also downloaded the Parse tutorial "IntegratingFacebookTutorial" and still the same error.

(I added the bundle to the facebook app and updated the application id on xcode as required.

The same happens in my own project when trying to use PFLogInViewController, same setup + I'm calling [PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebook]; in my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

I found several reports about this issue but zero solutions so far.

Answer (score 15):

Found a solution (will be happy to hear if its a valid solution)

In the facebook app (developer.facebook.com) -> Settings -> Advanced -> Is your app secret embedded -> Set to "No" and problem solved!

Comment: Your solution effectively does the trick! 2 thumbs up for your answer!

Comment: I don't see this in the advanced section anymore

Comment: @meisel , you need to turn on "Native or desktop app?" first.

Comment: I am developing for web. still i tried this solution. it doesnt seem to work. But if i clear cache and run the parse fb ligin script if works. is there a way to solve this?